# opencv with python filtering a color give error

Tags: python, opencv

what i am trying to do in my code below is to create an opencv program with python to open my laptop webcam and the filter the camera so that it will only show my clothes. but i coudnt even run the program because i have encounter an error that seem to be coming from the 10th line of the code. it is definitely not a misspeal error, i double checked it.

the code sample

```
#color filtering
import cv2
import numpy as np

#use camera
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
   `this line seem to be the source-->` hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)


    # hsv hue sat value
    # try to get the value of the color that you want
    lower_red = np.array([150,150,150])
    upper_red = np.array([180,255,255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask = mask)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('result',res)

    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#release camera
cap.release()
```

the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Program_Files/Python/legit8.py", line 10, in <module>
    hsv=cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:10705: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cv::cvtColor
```

Comment: wow thank you very much dude should have put this on answer, i would have give you thumbs up right away :D

Comment: I did and removed the comment, maybe I should have kept that lol glad to have helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your frame is probably `None`. This could be because of `VideoCapture(1)`. If your webcam is the only cam connected to your computer, use `VideoCapture(0)`!

Comment: If you're ever having trouble working with an image, *always* try to display it and print out the values and the dtype of the image to see if the data is as you are expecting it!